# Sudoku Checker in Java

Tags: java, validation, sudoku

```
public class SudokuChecker{ 

static int[][] sMatrix={

                    {5,3,4,6,7,8,9,1,2},
                    {6,7,2,1,9,5,3,4,8},
                    {1,9,8,3,4,2,5,6,7},
                    {8,5,9,7,6,1,4,2,3},
                    {4,2,6,8,5,3,7,9,1},
                    {7,1,3,9,2,4,8,5,6},
                    {9,6,1,5,3,7,2,8,4},
                    {2,8,7,4,1,9,6,3,5},
                    {3,4,5,2,8,6,1,7,9}
                };
static int rSum=0;

static int cSum=0;

static int[] rSumArray=new int[9];

static int[] cSumArray=new int[9];

static int[] boxSumArray=new int[9];

static boolean checkArrayStatus(int[] rSumArray,int[] cSumArray,int[] boxSumArray)
{   
    int i=0;

    boolean sudukoStatus=true;

    while(i<9){
        if(rSumArray[i]!=45&&cSumArray[i]!=45&&rSumArray[i]!=45)
        {   
            sudukoStatus=false;
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return sudukoStatus;
}   

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i=0 ; i<sMatrix.length ; i++){
            for(int j=0 ; j<sMatrix.length ; j++){
                rSum+=sMatrix[i][j];
                cSum+=sMatrix[j][i];
                }
            rSumArray[i]=rSum;
            cSumArray[i]=cSum;
            rSum=0;
            cSum=0;
        }

        for(int i=0 ; i< sMatrix.length ; i++){
            for(int j=0 ; j<sMatrix.length ; j++){
                if(i<=2&&j<=2)
                {
                    boxSumArray[0]+=sMatrix[i][j];
                }
                if(i<=2&&(j>=3&&j<=5))
                {
                    boxSumArray[1]+=sMatrix[i][j];
                }
                if(i<=2&&(j>=6&&j<=8))
                {
                    boxSumArray[2]+=sMatrix[i][j];
                }
                if((i>=3&&i<=5)&&(j<=2))
                {
                    boxSumArray[3]+=sMatrix[i][j];
                }
                if((i>=3&&i<=5)&&(j>=3&&j<=5))
                {
                    boxSumArray[4]+=sMatrix[i][j];
                }
                if((i>=3&&i<=5)&&(j>=6&&j<=8))
                {
                    boxSumArray[5]+=sMatrix[i][j];

                }
                if((i>=6)&&(j<=2))
                {
                    boxSumArray[6]+=sMatrix[i][j];
                }
                if((i>=6)&&(j>=3&&j<=5))
                {
                    boxSumArray[7]+=sMatrix[i][j];
                }
                if((i>=6)&&(j>=6))
                {
                    boxSumArray[8]+=sMatrix[i][j];
                }
            }
        }

        if(checkArrayStatus(rSumArray,cSumArray,boxSumArray))
        {
            System.out.println("The matrix is sudoku compliant");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("The matrix is not sudoku compliant");
        }
    }
}
```

This a program which verifies if a 2D matrix is a Sudoku or not. The sum of every row, column and 3x3 matrices have to be 45.  Please review the code and provide feedback on best practices and code optimization.

Comment: Hint why checking for `sum == 45` is not sufficient: `(1+9)+(2+8)+(3+7)+(4+6)+5` is OK, but `(1+9)+(1+9)+(1+9)+(1+9)+5` also fulfills that constraint!

Comment: @amon For lack of ability to think straight at the moment, is it possible to simultaneously fulfill the 45 sum on all rows and columns and mini-grids using numbers other than 1-9 once each?

Comment: Fill it all with 5. It sums 45 everywhere, but it is obviously not correct.

Comment: @amon...Your right...i didn't think of this...Though i wrote another program which checks for unique elements rowwise,colomnwise and in each 3x3 box......Can i check for unique numbers(1 to 9) rowwise and columnwise and say its a sudoku?Will there be a situation in which the sudoku passes for unique rowwise and columwise and not boxwise?

Comment: @user326744 conceerning that, Edward had concerns... under my post you can see a sudoku that qualifies...

Answer (score 28):

You have waaaay too many sums you are checking. [KISS-Principle --> Keep it Simple {and} Stupid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keep_it_simple_stupid):

```
private boolean checkSudokuStatus(int[][] grid) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {

        int[] row = new int[9];
        int[] square = new int[9];
        int[] column = grid[i].clone();

        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j ++) {
            row[j] = grid[j][i];
            square[j] = grid[(i / 3) * 3 + j / 3][i * 3 % 9 + j % 3];
        }
        if (!(validate(column) && validate(row) && validate(square)))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

private boolean validate(int[] check) {
    int i = 0;
    Arrays.sort(check);
    for (int number : check) {
        if (number != ++i)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

#### Short Explanation:

1. A Sudoku has three elements to validate. Each has to contain the single digit numbers from 1 to 9 exactly once.
2. These three elements are: each single row, each single column, the 9 3x3 sqares.
   These elements are exactly mapped by the three variables you see in the for-loop.
3. Each of these elements is given to a validate function to verify, that it contains the numbers only once. Originally this was a golfed solution, so the square calculation is heavily algorithmic.
4. The validate function is quite simple. It initializes a counter to 0, and then walks the sorted "validated element" through, while always incrementing by 1. this gives the numbers from 1 to 9. In fact it is just a shortened for-loop, written a little different it's:

this one

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 9; i++){
    if(check[i-1] != i){
       return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

#### Longer Explanation

How I got to the algorithmic generation for the squares:

```
[(i / 3) * 3 + j / 3]      [i * 3 % 9 + j % 3]
```

---

```
(i / 3) * 3 + j / 3
```

This part is relatively simple. It gives the correct "column" by help of implicit integer conversion: The first part of the equation is a little difficult:

> \$ (i / 3) \$
>   \$ {0,1,2} \mapsto 0 \$
>   \$ {3,4,5} \mapsto 1 \$
>   \$ {6,7,8} \mapsto 2 \$

take it `* 3` and you got the sqare you want to get in to. then if we now iterate row-wise, we need to jump to the next column every 3 Elements. That's done with `j / 3`.

Now for the difficult one:

```
 i * 3 % 9 + j % 3
```

> \$ (i * 3 \% 9) \$
>   \$ {0,3,6} \mapsto 0 \$
>   \$ {1,4,7} \mapsto 3 \$
>   \$ {2,5,8} \mapsto 6 \$

This one is for "jumping" the sqares vertically. Then we just have to iterate 0, 1, 2. This is accomplished by running the `% 3` operation.

Comment: Your variables `iterator` and `columnIterator` are very weird and hide their actual meaning – either use `i, j`, `row, column`, or `row, col`.

Comment: @amon row an column are taken, also I don't understand how you mean "hide their actual meaning", but I edited either way ;)

Comment: (There are no `java.util.Iterator`s here, but you have integer indices)

Comment: @amon I fully ignored that. not using Iterator much, thanks for the hint ;)

Comment: @Edward sure:    { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 },
   { 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 },
   { 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 },
   { 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 },
   { 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },
   { 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4 },
   { 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3 },
   { 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2 },
   { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1 } \*this really is missing code-formatting*

Comment: @vogel.....Am still new to java but doesnt this fill up elements from the grid array columnwise and not rowwise?  row[j] = grid[j][i];

Comment: @vogel how did you arrive at that square[j] = grid[(i / 3) * 3 + j / 3][i * 3 % 9 + j % 3];

Comment: @user concerning the first: that depends on which iterator you see as row, and which you see as column... in fact you are correct that it takes the "columns". Concerning the second, you might want to take a look at the answer from UriAgassi. It's about the same, just inverted....

Comment: @user3296744 I added some explanation

Answer (score 9):

**Mind your scope**
You have a lot of `static` members (`cSum`, `rSum`, etc.), which you calculate in one method, and the pass them as arguments to other methods. This means that they should be members at all - they should be declared locally, and not be exposed outside the method. This way you can be sure no-one else is changing them when you are not looking...

**What should a `main` method do?**
Your `main` method contains *a lot* of functionality. I suggest you move this functionality to another method (`checkBoard()`). This way, when you decide to take this code, and use it as a module in another application, you can simply do it!

**Keep it DRY**
As a programmer, you should have bells ringing in your head each time you find yourself using `Copy+Paste`. Say you find a bug in your code, now you have to fix it 9 times! and if you miss a fix somewhere - good luck finding where it is...
Take the similarities between your snippets, and refactor them out. Analyze the differences, and pass them as arguments. Find how you decide which argument values to pass, and develop an algorithm to make that decision for you:

```
for(int i=0 ; i< sMatrix.length ; i++){
   for(int j=0 ; j<sMatrix.length ; j++){
       int boxIndex = (i / 3) * 3 + j / 3;
       boxSumArray[boxIndex]+=sMatrix[i][j];
   }
}
```

Comment: @uri....Thanks for your feedback...How did you come up with this  int boxIndex = i % 3 * 3 + j % 3 ?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake - it should be `/`, not `%` (modulo) - I fixed my answer...

Comment: In many cases I would also suggest moving the functionality out of the class and into its instances, although that doesn't really apply in this case.

Answer (score 7):

Just a couple of minor things:

- In Java, `{` braces should be put at the end of the same line and not on it's own line.
- Instead of using break and a `boolean sudokuStatus` in your `checkArrayStatus` method, use a `return` statement

  ```
  while (i < 9) {
      if (rSumArray[i] != 45 && cSumArray[i] != 45 && rSumArray[i] != 45) {   
          return false;
      }
      i++;
  }
  return true;
  ```
- Since the above loop is just doing a fixed-length iteration, replace `while (i < 9)` with

  ```
  for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
  ```
- 9 is a "magic number" in your code. Let's say you wanted to change the Sudoku grid size (there are 4x4 Sudokus as well, in fact, almost any size is possible). If you wanted to change the size, you'd have to replace the value in many different places. Instead use a constant.

  ```
  public static final int GRID_SIZE = 9;
  ```

  Now, instead of writing `9` you can use `GRID_SIZE`

## And one major thing:

Just because some numbers sum up to 45 doesn't mean that it's valid in a Sudoku group!

Consider these numbers: `1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 9, 9, 9, 9`. Do they some up to 45? Yes. Would it be a valid group/row/column in a Sudoku? **NO!** This is why @Vogel612's solution is a whole lot better.

Comment: @simon.....Yes i agree to what you said!

Comment: :Instead of using break and a boolean sudokuStatus in your checkArrayStatus method, use a return statement....Can you tell me why this is prefered over a booleanStatus?

Comment: :since the above loop is just doing a fixed-length iteration, replace while (i < 9) with for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)...why is this prefered over a normal for loop?